# If I am using pandas .to_excel, how do I assign a worksheet to a variable?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, xlsxwriter

I have written an Excel sheet like so

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('test.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='sheet_name', header=True, index=True)
```

Now I want to add a text box to the worksheet. How do I assign the sheet to a variable to add a text box?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```py
import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame({'Data': [10, 20, 30, 20, 15, 30, 45]})

writer = pd.ExcelWriter('pandas_textbox.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')

df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1')

workbook  = writer.book
worksheet = writer.sheets['Sheet1']

worksheet.insert_textbox(2, 3, "Hello world")

writer.save()
```

**Output**:

[image]

See [Working with Python Pandas and XlsxWriter](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_pandas.html).

Comment: This is actually one of the nicest answers I've gotten on stackoverflow. So thank you a lot